# How to extract a portion of URL using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my first program with both Python and Scrapy.  I have a URL with the following format:

```
/product/123?type=some-type
```

I want to extract the id (i.e. 123) from the URL. So it would be the alphanumeric string before `?` and after `product/`

Comment: How about using regex like this:
`re.findall(r'product/([\d]+)', 'product/123?type=some-type')`

Comment: @Kishan, thanks for your help